# Regex help nedded

Tags: regex

I need to match any kind of string which has at least a . (dot) and a * (star) character and not a < or > (html tags). Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using? Would it be appropriate to suggest a non-regex solution in this language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^ [^<>]* ( \. [^<>]* \* | \* [^<>]* \.) [^<>]* $` (sans the spaces), but two regexes would be easier.

In Perl: `/^[^<>]*\.[^<>]*$/ and /^[^<>]*\*[^<>]*$/`

Answer (score 4):

I think the following would work, but I don't think regex is the easiest way to solve this problem.

```
^[^<>]*(\.[^<>]*\*|\*[^<>]*\.)[^<>]*$
```

Comment: as you said: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/great-programming-quotes/58646#58646 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`^([^<>.]*\.[^<>*]\*)|([^<>*]*\*[^<>.]\.)[^<>]*$`

This is similar to the answer provided by Mark Byers, but should be more efficient because it reduces backtracking.

Explanation:  The initial `^` character specifies that the pattern applies to the entire string.  Then, the string can contain one of two patterns:

- A period followed by zero or more
  characters that are not `<` or `>`,
  and an asterisk, OR
- An asterisk followed by zero or
  more characters that are not `<`
  or `>`, and a period.

After either of those is satisfied, the string can contain any number (zero or more) characters that are not `<` or `>`.

Comment: Voted up for providing an explanation.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem though. dot AND asterisk. Both conditions must be met.

Comment: Almost.. the parenthesis could be moved as follows.. ^([^<>.]*\.[^<>*]*|[^<>*]*\\*[^<>.]\.)[^<>]*$ but is a potentially more efficient query.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^<>]*(\.[^<>]*\*|\*[^<>]*\.)[^<>]*$
```

For further experimentation, use [rubular](http://rubular.com/), a live regex checker.

Comment: Fails. Has to have a dot AND a star.

Comment: That's dot *or* star. I think he wants dot *and* star.